# Format(line wrapping) constructor initializer list in Eclipse CDT

Tags: c++, eclipse, constructor, formatting, eclipse-cdt

I tried to find a solution for now ~30min and couldn't find any.
I am trying to set up the code style in CDT so it gives me:

```
MyClass::MyClass() :    
var1(1), 
var2(2), 
var3(3){

}
```

instead of

```
MyClass::MyClass() :    
var1(1), var2(2), var3(3){

}
```

but I couldn't find an option to do so.

The only 'initializer list' option I could find is actually for arrays and therefore not useful for me.

My question is: Am I missing the right spot? Is there a plug-in out there which does better formatting of C++ code than CDT?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? If so could you post it as an answer to your question?

Comment: Sorry for the late comment: no I've never found an answer.

Comment: take a look to the answer.. just a little in late! (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Eric provides manual solution, but to make this setting auomatic, you need to edit eclipse preferences.

Click on:
**Window -> Preferences**

Go to:
**C/C++ -> Code Style -> Formatter**

Here, as first thing you have to create a new profile.

Select tab:
**Line Wrapping**

Go to:
**Function declarations -> Constructor initializer list**

On the bottom, you have to set:

- Line wrapping policy: **Wrap all elements, every element on a new line.**
- check **"Force split, even if line is shorter than maximum"**
- Indentation policy: **indent on column**

Comment: This seems indeed the correct way to do this. Has this been added in 4.3 or did I completely miss it?

Comment: I can't verify this.. which version you used?

Comment: I just found someone in my office who still had 4.2 (Juno) installed. This was the version I asked the question for. And indeed you solution is available even in 4.2. Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm glad I helped you. It took me half an hour of searching too, but great and usefull discovery anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I can't tell you exactly how to do this but if you don't mind a little extra  white space I can get you close. Enter a blank line between each line. That is:

```
MyClass::MyClass() :    
var1(1), 

var2(2), 

var3(3){
}
```

Now when you reformat, this layout will stick. I know it's not exactly what you want but I thought I would post just in case you didn't know about this work-around.

Comment: Thanks for posting this. Your are right, it is not perfect, but suitable for short lists.

This will work for some of my classes, thx!

Comment: You can always group related  multiple items (that are short enough) on one line and then use this technique to separate groups. I find myself using this more and more to *manually* control my initializer lists. To me, it's **very** important to be able to quickly scan and modify my initializer lists. My lint settings are set up so that I have to initialize all member vars in the proper order in the initializer list. I find it helpful to set my maximum line width to 120.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. I dont have the CDT package so I cannot test this, but the formatting does something similar in Java.

If you put a comment at the end of a line, it will keep the newline

```
MyClass::MyClass() : //
var1(1), //
var2(2), //
var3(3){ //

}
```

Comment: The first initialiser has a different indent than all others. Not ideal but much better than the spacing method. I gladly accept this as a solution :).